# How to make a dataframe from print result in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to print my for loop results in to a dataframe. Here is my for loop..

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("/data/rrd_dump_xml/"):
    if filename.endswith(".xml") : 
        totaldir="/data/rrd_dump_xml/"+filename
     
        tree=et.parse(totaldir)
        root=tree.getroot()
        NAME = []
        for name in root.iter('name'):
            NAME.append(name.text)
        UPDATE = []
        for update in root.iter('lastupdate'):
             UPDATE.append(update.text)
        updated = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(UPDATE[0]))
        lastupdate=updated.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        ParaValue = []
        for parameterevalue in root.iter('value'):
            ParaValue.append(parameterevalue.text)
            
        
        print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[0],ParaValue[0])
        print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[1],ParaValue[1])
       
        
    else:
        print("Error")
```

I need to get an dataframe with below format of column headers..

```
filename lastupdate Name Value
```

Note: In each file in for loop, there will be two print results( `print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[0],ParaValue[0])` and  `print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[1],ParaValue[1])`  )

can some one help me to do this? I checked with some examples
[Writing output of a for loop to pandas data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174436/writing-output-of-a-for-loop-to-pandas-data-frame)  but when I use those methods I am not getting correct output.

Tried sample answer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cutoff_list , number_list)), 
           columns =['cutoff', 'number'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the output, add it to a list, and convert the list to a dataframe.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

content = []
for filename in os.listdir("/data/rrd_dump_xml/"):
    if filename.endswith(".xml") : 
        totaldir="/data/rrd_dump_xml/"+filename
     
        tree=et.parse(totaldir)
        root=tree.getroot()
        NAME = []
        for name in root.iter('name'):
            NAME.append(name.text)
        UPDATE = []
        for update in root.iter('lastupdate'):
             UPDATE.append(update.text)
        updated = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(UPDATE[0]))
        lastupdate=updated.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        ParaValue = []
        for parameterevalue in root.iter('value'):
            ParaValue.append(parameterevalue.text)

        # print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[0],ParaValue[0])            
        content.append({"filename": filename,
                        "lastupdate": lastupdate,
                        "Name": NAME[0],
                        "Value": ParaValue[0]})

        # print(filename,lastupdate,NAME[1],ParaValue[1])
        content.append({"filename": filename,
                        "lastupdate": lastupdate,
                        "Name": NAME[1],
                        "Value": ParaValue[1]})
       
        
    else:
        print("Error")

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(content)
```